# jQuery blur() appears on focus

Tags: javascript, blur

I want to validate each input of a form on blur() so if user leaves the input box.

```
$("form#relative_form :input").blur(function() {
   var input = $(this).attr('id');
   alert("Validate: " + input);
});
```

It works fine but when i'm in the first input field and hit TAB to get to the next input field,
my script straight validate the second input.
But I want only to validate if i leave the inputs.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rh7zx25h/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The alert is causing the object to lose focus triggering the blur. Use Console.log() to test instead:

```
$("form#relative_form :input").blur(function() {
    var input = $(this).attr('id'); // This is the jquery object of the input, do what you will
    console.log("Validate: " + input);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine!!!

> But Instead of the alert you must need to use console.log().If you are
>   using alert then it will continuous call blur function because you are
>   trying to close the alert box and at that time it will call blur
>   event.So it's something like **circular function.**

Instead of:

```
$("form#relative_form :input").blur(function() {
   var input = $(this).attr('id');
   alert("Validate: " + input);
});
```

It should be:

```
$("form#relative_form :input").blur(function() {
   var input = $(this).attr('id');
   console.log("Validate: " + input);
});
```